# Spring Data MongoDB - when saving LocaDate/LocalDateTime the value is being set to yesterday

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I've got a problem with saving Java8 Date API values to MongoDB database. Whenever a new LocalDate instance (LocalDate.now()) is being saved, as a result we are getting value with yesterdays date with time set to 23:00 PM. 
Example:

```
dt.getDate().toString()
```

is giving me "2017-03-17"

but when i look into the database i have a value like this:

```
"dt" : ISODate("2017-03-16T23:00:00.000Z")
```

My time zone is UTC+01:00

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoDB saves the date in UTC time.

LocalTime is your wall clock time.

When you pass it to MongoDb, spring will convert the `LocalTime` to `Instant`(UTC time) by using your System Zone.

Consider

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-17T00:00:00")
```

Something like this happpens

```
Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

This is where your local time is changed to UTC instant by applying offset (+01:00) from your local time.

```
Output(in UTC) : 2017-03-16T23:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: What if I am already giving it UTC time and don't want mongo to convert it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Taher What is your date type ? If it is `Instant` then the spring mongo will persist as is in UTC time.

Comment: I figured it out. I was giving `LocalDateTime` to mongo and since LocalDateTime does not have timezone information, mongo driver will assume it is of System Time zone and then convert it to UTC. If I give it a regular `Date` object which has zone information (UTC in my case) mongo did not do any conversion.